# How to fix "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err.response.data')"

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a react app with redux as state manager. All the actions work fine on the desktop but crash as soon as I try to use the app on iOS.
For example, I have a login page and it functions as you would expect on the desktop web browser but on ios, I get this error - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err.response.data').

I have attached my redux store file below

Initially I thought it was an error with the redux dev tools but even after removing that line of code, it still crashes

```
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'
const middleware = [thunk];
const initialState = {};



const getComposeEnhancers = () => {
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome')) {
    return compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
  } else

    return compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
};



const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  initialState,
  getComposeEnhancers()
);

export default store;
```

````
// This is the authActions file, responsible for registering and login
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';
import {GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER} from './types';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

//register

export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios.post(`${url}/auth/register`, userData)
       .then(res=>{history.push('/login')

     }).catch(err=> dispatch({
       type: GET_ERRORS,
       payload: err.response.data
     }))
}

//login 
export const loginUser = (userData)=> dispatch=>{
  axios.post(`${url}/auth/login`, userData)
        .then(res=>{
          //save to local storage
          const {token} = res.data;
          //set token to localstorage
          localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', token);
          //set token to auth header
          setAuthToken(token);
          //decode token to get userData
          const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
          //set current user
          dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))

        }).catch(err=> dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        }))
}

//set logged in user

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded)=>{
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  }
}


//log out user
export const logoutUser=()=>dispatch=>{
//rm jwt_token
localStorage.removeItem('jwt_token');
//rm auth header
setAuthToken(false);
//set setCurrentUser to {}
dispatch(setCurrentUser({}))


}```
````

Comment: what is being printed when logging `err` before dispatching the action?

Comment: I am not able to see that on the mobile

Comment: try `console.warn` instead

Comment: The problem was with the request url. Instead of localhost, I put the IP address of my computer and it worked.Thank you